# jQuery widget call private function from event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

I have a jQuery ui widget which has a link in it's content

```
 <a href="test" data-foo="clickThis">Click me</a>
```

in `_create` function I attach click event handler and create instance variable

```
_create: function () {
   //*this* here refers to widget
   this.$elem.on('click', 'a[data-foo]', this._clickHandler);
   this.instanceVariable = "someValue";
}

_clickHandler: function (event) {
   //**this** in here refers to link, not to widget
   //Question: How to call _otherPrivateFunction from here 
}

_otherPrivateFunction(){
  //I want to access this.instanceVariable in here
}
```

I have multiple instances of widget on one page, so each one should access it's own instanceVariable. 
One way I found to do this, is to pass `this` as `event.data` to the click handler, however I don't like this solution, as this is just some workaround.

```
this.$elem.on('click', 'a[data-foo]', this, this._clickHandler);
```

I would appreciate some better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a custom execution context to the click handler using [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) then `this` inside the event handler will point to the widget so you can call `this._otherPrivateFunction()` from the handler method

```
this.$elem.on('click', 'a[data-foo]', $.proxy(this._clickHandler, this));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) saved a lot of my time :)